# How to get installed patch list?

Tags: powershell

I have used below code to fetch installed software patch list in Windows server, but I am not able to find the exact match as below code used to get history of patch list. Means it's showing after uninstallation also same details.  Could you please help me to get only available software patch list after install and uninstall operation?

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$a = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Title
$a
```

Comment: use the `Search()` method instead of `Queryhistory()`? Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried that too as well having issue to test particular KBarticle how to test particular KBarticle is installed or not ? Thanks gvee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on n information from @OP.

Now searching all (non-hidden) updates for a given KBArticleID to find out whether it is installed or not.

```
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=vs.85).aspx
$session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$searcher = $session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$searchResults = $searcher.Search("IsHidden = 0")
$updates = $searchResults.Updates

$kbid = "4054517"
$updates | Where-Object KBArticleIDs -Contains $kbid | Select-Object Title, IsInstalled
```

Note that this can include multiple results e.g.

[image: Results]

Comment: can we able to check particular KB article is not installed? do we have any possibility ?
 Thanks gvee for detailed code

Comment: ...`IsInstalled = 0`?

Comment: @hasini answer updated. Does that give you what you need?

Comment: Thanks i made little different.